# How to get collections from sub-folder in docpad?

Tags: docpad

my folds structure are something like this:

- documents

  - techs

    - docs

I want to get a collection from docs, my code is :

```
techs: ->
        @getCollection("html").findAllLive({relativeOutDirPath: /techs/docs/},[{date: -1}]).on "add", (model) ->
            model.setMetaDefaults({layout: "post"})
```

It just won't works... Could somebody tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

The `/techs/docs/` in `{relativeOutDirPath: /techs/docs/}` is parsed as a regular expression, rather than a string. Wrap it in quotes so you have `{relativeOutDirPath: "/techs/docs/"}` instead. You may or may not need the initial slash, I can't remember.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the convenient helper provided by Docpad : [getFilesAtPath](http://docpad.org/docs/template-data).

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question! Actually I don't quite understand how to use this helper in this case...

And I just find out that if set the `relativeOutDirPath` to `docs`, then it works just fine. Seems like it can't process `techs/docs`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read the file "docpad.coffee"

There is a section "collection", you can set collection named "html", and select all files in (database).

Comment: You should improve this answer by providing citations and examples.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems depending on what system I'm running node.js and docpad on (ie Windows) with file path conventions. So I resort to the following to make sure I'm not having any of those sort of problems:

```
 @getCollection("html").findAllLive({relativeOutDirPath:path.join('techs','docs')},[date:-1])
```

Note the 'path.join' bit

Answer (score 0):

Just as example, all html documents from path starts with "post"

```
@getCollection("html").findAllLive({relativeOutDirPath: {$beginsWith: 'post'}})
```