# Get all pages from subdir and actually dir

Tags: docpad

I have problem with docpad. I would like to get all pages from subdirectory.

I found this post:

[How to get collections from sub-folder in docpad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375086/how-to-get-collections-from-sub-folder-in-docpad)

[docpad subdirectory rendered into general directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18809753/docpad-subdirectory-rendered-into-general-directory)

but it doesn't work for me.

**My tree structure:**

- documents

  - places

    - place1

      - home
      - page1
    - place2

      - home
      - page2
    - etc ...

**My code - get all pages (from place1 and place2)**

```
<ul class="list-group"> 
<% for add in @getFilesAtPath("places").findAll().toJSON(): %>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href="<%= add.url %>">
            <%= add.title %>
        </a>
    </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

**My code - don't get page from places/place1 - is empty**

```
<ul class="list-group"> 
<% for add in @getFilesAtPath("places/place1").findAll().toJSON(): %>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href="<%= add.url %>">
            <%= add.title %>
        </a>
    </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

My target is, when Im on place1/home I would like to display all pages from actually dir (place1). When Im on place2/home - show all pages from place2.

**How to do this?**

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in one answer in one of you referenced questions [How to get collections from sub-folder in docpad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18764675/2135716), the path is system "dependent".

I'm running Docpad on Windows and test the following and it works.

```
<ul class="list-group"> 
  <% for add in @getFilesAtPath("places\\place1").findAll().toJSON(): %>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <a href="<%= add.url %>">
        <%= add.title %>
      </a>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

---

To make the solution system agnostic you can...

Add a helper that normalize the path separator.

```
normalizePathSeparator: (unixPath) -> unixPath.replace('/', path.sep)
```

Use like that:

```
<ul class="list-group"> 
  <% for add in @getFilesAtPath(@normalizePathSeparator("places/place1")).findAll().toJSON(): %>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <a href="<%= add.url %>">
        <%= add.title %>
      </a>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

---

PS: You'll need to require the `path` module in your `docpad.coffee` file.